# Disable mouse wheel integration in Android emulator

Tags: android-studio, scroll, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, magic-mouse

Is it possible to **disable mouse wheel scrolling in AVD**? Because I am using apple magic mouse and almost every mouse touch (not click - just touch) acts as click in Emulator and it drives me crazy.

Same thing is happening even on BlueStacks emulator but I do not use it for now.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am experiencing the same issue and it drives me crazy! Help :)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still waiting for advice.

Comment: I put this into issue tracker of AOSP. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62989343

Comment: I'm going through the exact same thing... it is absolutely annoying lmao.

Comment: how can I upvote this 25 more times?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To expand on the accepted answer: While your emulator is running, you should have a narrow panel next to it with buttons for rotating the screen etc. At the bottom of this is an overflow menu which takes you to "extended controls". The Settings page in here contains the fabled "Disable mouse wheel" switch.

This used to drive me insane - the idea that it is an acceptable default behaviour is ridiculous. Anyway, the switch works and now I can use my emulator again!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems it’s going to be fixed as an option in AVD settings:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37150562